# How to keep Dwarf Fortress running?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I think I've established a self-contained dwarf fortress, and want to see what it would become without my intervention.

The problem is, [Major announcements](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Announcement#Major_announcements) automatically stop the game, and I have to unpause it later manually. How can I keep the game running until the doom of my fortress?